# Is it possible to compare two cursors value?

Tags: android, sql, cursor

I need to check if two cursors pointing at the same rows with the same values. Is it possible?

Mode detail.
1. First cursorOne have completed data of message.
2. Second cursorTwo have count of unRead message.

Code:

```
Cursor inboxSMSCursor = ApplicationClass.getInstance().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(DBContentProvider.USER_INFO_URI+ "/" + 0), new String[]{
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_DISPLAY_NAME,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER_LOGO,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_MESSAGE,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_FIRST_TIME,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_LABEL,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_TREAD_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_MY_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SECOND_TIME,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SUB_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_READ_STATUS,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SPAM_STATUS,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER_PARENT},
                UserInboxInfo.KEY_SPAM_STATUS+" = 0",
                null,
                UserInboxInfo.KEY_TREAD_ID + " DESC");

        // need to improve this logic
        Cursor getUnReadCount = ApplicationClass.getInstance().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(DBContentProvider.USER_INFO_URI+ "/" + 0), new String[]{
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_GROUP_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_TREAD_ID,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_READ_STATUS,
                        UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER_PARENT,
                        "count("+UserInboxInfo.KEY_SENDER_PARENT+") as countTx"
                },
                UserInboxInfo.KEY_READ_STATUS+" = 0 AND "+
                UserInboxInfo.KEY_SPAM_STATUS+" = 0",
                null, UserInboxInfo.KEY_TREAD_ID + " DESC");
```

Now I want the value of unRead message count as per cursorOne treadId. It is possible?

Comment: Can you share me an example

Comment: find related solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812250/is-it-possible-to-compare-two-cursors

Comment: Read DOC https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwimorC40JDWAhUFqo8KHaARCp8QFgg3MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fdatabase%2FCursorJoiner.html&usg=AFQjCNHltCIsMCrPGw3EBPD55lR0TcNvXQ

Comment: CursorJoiner: sample code here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html

Comment: How can I get cursorTwo countTx value using cursorOne Id ?

Comment: you will get cursor's data by using one of `Cursor#get*` methods

Comment: I have done that but not giving required result

Comment: so what result are you getting? did you try to call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` in the iterator's loop?

Comment: Yes I did It is adding both cursor value. I want common value

Comment: it is adding what? i have no idea what you mean